# How rosbridge finds custom messages?

Tags: ros-kinetic, rosbridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to subscribe a custom message from a rosbridge server.
First I create a custom package and message by following the ROS official tutorial. Then build with catkin tool with `catkin_make install`. After source the .bash file I could successfully see my .msg through `rosmsg show`, or find my package though `rospack find`. However, when I use my client to request my custom message, it shows:

```
subscribe: Unable to import my_pack.msg from package my_pack. Caused by: No module named my_pack.msg
```

Note: I am using [roslibpy](https://github.com/gramaziokohler/roslibpy/) as client side to connect to rosbridge server. Also Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS kinetic

I think my question would be: how rosbridge locates ROS packages? Should I add additional env var such that ROS bridge could find my package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/317621/how-rosbridge-finds-custom-messages?/) by [wthwlh](https://answers.ros.org/users/40343/wthwlh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2019-03-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:\

> Should I add additional env var such that ROS bridge could find my package?

No, that should not be necessary.

Are you starting the `rosapi_node`? That is required for `rosbridge` to understand what msgs/srvs/actions exist.

Which launch file do you use to start `rosbridge`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@gvdhoom Thanks for the reply, I have figured that out, it turns out I didn't source my setup.bash in that rosbridge server window...That is stupid...

---

Originally posted by [wthwlh](https://answers.ros.org/users/40343/wthwlh/) with karma: 26 on 2019-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-06**:
Well .. that would certainly be required, yes.